# Access UI Control by ID/Indentifier in Swift [Mac OSX]?

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to be able to access a UI control (ie: a `NSTextField`) by ID (or Identifier).

I can do: `sender.identifier` to get the ID I want but I cannot seem to get/set values.

For example: If I have a button called, ***Button_01*** when the user clicks this button I would want to update a field called, ***Name_01***. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every NSControl in Mac OS has a tag property (previously -tag and -setTag:)

```
@property NSInteger tag; // Obj-C
var tag: Int // Swift
```

This allows you to attribute any control with a number value. So if you had a bunch of buttons that you want to differentiate by tag, you could write some code like:

```
button1.tag = 1; // Obj-C/Swift code (can omit the ; in Swift)
button2.tag = 2;
```

Then you can simply compare the tag of the sender. If you're working with xibs or storyboards in Mac OS, you can also set these values in Interface Builder.

NSControl being a subclass of NSView then has the method `func viewWithTag(_ aTag: Int) -> AnyObject?` which can be used in the following way:

```
let buttonWithTag = containerView.viewWithTag(tag)
```

Where `containerView` is the view containing all your buttons for example and the `tag` is the tag you gave to each button previously.

Answer (score 0):

First: You should create and Outlet for the Object, for Example the "Name_01" (this is a bad Name for a TextField)

Then you can easily update it with:

```
txtFieldName.text = ""
```

OR: if you want to use an Identifier, you can set an Tag ID for every View Element, and get this Element with:

```
viewWithTag(ID)
```